# angular function call before html view is load

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs (1.6) and want to made a functionality in angular service, its call when a controller call and its service have an ajax code like

```
app.service('myServ', function($http, $window){
this.backdoor=function(){
    $http({
        method : 'get',
        url : 'web_services/backdoor.php'
    }).then(function(res){
        // console.log(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data.length);
        if(res.data.length==0)
        {   
            $window.location.href="index.html";
        }
    });
}});
```

and my controller code is :

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, myServ, $routeParams){
        myServ.backdoor();
    });
```

so the above code (service) is check a user session is created or not, but the problem is when session is not created on server side then my html page load for a second then server will call $window.location.href so please help me about the right way to do this....

Comment: you mean to say ang service fired before session creation ? is that so , then can't you create a session on application events i.e appstart.

Comment: to run the code before it is rendered or executed in the controller, you need to [**resolve**](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) it in `angular.config`. It will run some logic while routing between pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a **resolve** in `angular.config`. Its job is to run some code before you are being redirected to your route/state (for `ngRoute` or `ui.router`).

To do that you would need to have:

```
app.service('myServ', function($http, $window){
this.backdoor=function(){
    return $http({ // return the promise if you need to use the values in the controller
        method : 'get',
        url : 'web_services/backdoor.php'
    }).then(function(res){
        if(res.data.length==0){ $window.location.href="index.html"; }
        else{ return res.data; }  // return the values
    });
}});
```

and main part:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/your_page/:route_params', {
        templateUrl: 'your_page_partial.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl',
        resolve: {
          resolvedVal: function resMyService(myServ, $routeParams){ // setting an injectable instance `resolvedVal` 
            /* use $routeParams values as parameters? */
            return myServ.backdoor(); // calling your service
          }
        }}
      );
}]);
```

Then it's enough to just inject your resolve into the controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, resolvedVal){ // note: resolvedVal injection
  $scope.my_data = resolvedVal; 
});
```